# Python 3.7.0: How do I format datetime to mm-dd-yy hh:mm:ss?

Tags: python-3.x, date, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

How do I format datetime to mm-dd-yy hh:mm:ss? I did it using the following code:

```
import datetime
t = datetime.datetime.now()

s = str(format(t.second, '02d'))
m = str(format(t.minute, '02d'))
h = str(format(t.hour, '02d'))

d = str(format(t.day, '02d'))
mon = str(format(t.month, '02d'))
y = str(t.year)

x = '-'
z = ':'
print(mon + x + d + x + y + '   ' + h + z + m + z + s)
```

but the problem is, first of all, the year prints in YYYY instead of YY (I only want the last two digits of the year). Second of all, I'm sure there's an easier way to print datetime in mm-dd-yy hh:mm:ss instead of doing it manually like I did.
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like this:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
now.strftime('%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S')
```

Also see docs - https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: Thanks. I also discovered you could do:

    t='{0:%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())
          print(t)
and that gives the same result. What's the difference though? How is your way making it work and how is my way making it work?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

read this paragraph. You will be using strftime to convert datetime to your desired format.

Also check the table. in the link